Newgate, say: an old cryptic clue
I recently came across an old notebook of mine where I'd written down the following:

Newgate, say, one leading hell (3, 4)

(I know, not the smoothest surface reading!) For the life of me I can't figure out what I intended the answer to be, so I was hoping someone at PSE could help me out. I have a vague notion that

"one leading hell" was intended to be the definition, but I may be misremembering.


To be clear: the above is a true story, not some sort of flavortext.

This likely has the intended solution:

 OLD NICK

 This is both a nickname for the Devil (hence 'one leading hell') and a reference to Newgate Prison, a London jail that was demolished in 1904. In Britain, 'the nick' is a slang term for prison - so one that is no longer in use could be an 'old nick' in a cryptic definition.


Thanks, I'm sure that's it! Now my mind can be at ease.
